# Configuring ActiveStorage to use S3 with IAM role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm trying to configure ActiveStorage to use S3 bucket as a storage backend however I don't want to pass  any of `access_key_id`, `secret_access_key`, `region`. Instead, I'd like to use previously defined IAM role. Such configuration is mentioned [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#amazon-s3-service). It reads (I've added bold):

> If you want to use environment variables, standard SDK configuration files, profiles, **IAM instance profiles** or task roles, you can omit the access_key_id, secret_access_key, and region keys in the example above. The Amazon S3 Service supports all of the authentication options described in the AWS SDK documentation.

However I cannot get it working. My `storage.yml` looks similar to  this:

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  bucket: bucket_name
  credentials:
    role_arn: "linked::account::arn"
    role_session_name: "session-name"
```

I've run `rails active_storage:install`, applied generated migrations and set `config.active_storage.service = :amazon` in my app's config.

The issue is that when I'm trying to save a file, I'm getting an unexpected error:

```rb
u = User.first
s = StringIO.new
s << 'hello,world'
s.seek 0
u.csv.attach(io: s, filename: 'filename.csv')

Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):3
        1: from (irb):3:in `rescue in irb_binding'
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant ActiveStorage::Blob::Analyzable, expected /usr/local/bundle/gems/activestorage-5.2.2/app/models/active_storage/blob/analyzable.rb to define it)
```

I'm using Rails 5.2.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you trying this code inside an AWS EC2 instance or locally in your machine?

If you check the authentication methods in AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/setup-config.html#aws-ruby-sdk-credentials-iam

You'll see the following section:

> Setting Credentials Using IAM
>
> For an Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud instance, create an AWS Identity and Access Management role, and then
>   give your Amazon EC2 instance access to that role. For more
>   information, see IAM Roles for Amazon EC2 in the Amazon EC2 User Guide
>   for Linux Instances or IAM Roles for Amazon EC2 in the Amazon EC2 User
>   Guide for Windows Instances.

This means that for this authentication method to work, you must:

- Create an EC2 instance on AWS
- Create an EC2 **IAM Role** with permissions to write to an S3 Bucket
- Configure your EC2 instance attaching the new IAM Role to it

With the role attached to the instance, your **config/storage.yml** file will look like this:

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  bucket: test-stackoverflow-bucket-app
  region: "us-west-1"
```

Note that region is a required parameter, you'll get an error if you skip it: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/1240#issuecomment-231866239

I'm afraid this won't work locally, to use `active_storage` locally you must set the `access_key_id`, `secret_access_key` values.

Comment: Am getting access denied error though my ec2 instance having full S3 access.
Is it mandatory to set AWS STS Access Token