# Failing to set credentials for Rails project to use S3 with IAM role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, rails-activestorage

I'm using ActiveStorage to upload files to S3 bucket. If anyone is familiar with Heroku Bucketeer add-on, I used it for a while to test ActiveStorage and uploading and downloading files to and from the bucket worked.

For certain reasons, I have to set credentials to new Amazon S3 bucket with only bucket name and region, using IAM role. In ActiveStorage RubyOnRails guide it says:

> If you want to use environment variables, standard SDK configuration files, profiles, IAM instance profiles or task roles, you can omit the access_key_id, secret_access_key, and region keys in the example above.

However I get

```
(Aws::Sigv4::Errors::MissingCredentialsError)
- :access_key_id and :secret_access_key
- :credentials
- :credentials_provider
```

my storage.yml looks like this:

```
amazon:   
  service: S3   
  bucket: <%= ENV['BUCKET_NAME'] %>   
  region: <%= ENV['AWS_REGION'] %>
```

I have written `config.active_storage.service = :amazon` both in development.rb and production.rb

I already tried [Configuring ActiveStorage to use S3 with IAM role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55188016/configuring-activestorage-to-use-s3-with-iam-role), but in vain.

I'm using Rails 5.2.4.1, Ruby 2.6.3, and have `gem 'aws-sdk'` in Gemfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Especially when working in development you will need to provided an `access_key_id` and a `secret_access_key`. You can do this by putting in `storage.yml`:

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %> 
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
  bucket: <%= ENV['BUCKET_NAME'] %>   
  region: <%= ENV['AWS_REGION'] %>
```

Alternatively, ensure that you have set the right environment variables, to enable the implicit lookup of your aws credentials, as specified by [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/a-new-and-standardized-way-to-manage-credentials-in-the-aws-sdks/). That is, set the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`

Comment: with access and secret_access key yes. However I was ordered to write it without use of those two and, as far as I know, you can omit those two with the use of IAM role

Comment: The IAM role is there to provide access to certain services using policies assigned to that role. However you have to indicate somehow which role is applying to your application. If you are deploying on Heroku, the application can not know nor authenticate for a specific role.

Comment: I'm not deploying for heroku, I just brought it up as an example that ActiveStorage works. So what should I do if I want to connect to S3 without secret_access_key and access_key?

Comment: Well, you can't really, unless you are deploy inside of AWS using a specific service like Lambda. So for local development, or any other deployment method, you should at provide the environment variables as specified in my answer.

Comment: @GiorgiMeladze was my answer helpful enough to give it an upvote/mark it as answered?

Comment: Yeah it was helpful enough to give an up-vote, unfortunately I can't give away up-votes yet due to reputation shortage. I'll use what you have written to solve my issue, Thank you

Comment: Ah okay, but you could accept it as answer right? :-)